# select the right database according to input login field

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have 3 login fields (name, pass, company id). Now when user clicks "Log me in" button CI should select and work with database according to company id (and check user in this database and when he is logged in, work with this database over whole session /each company has its own database/).

How can I do this?

I found **[this](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/145901/)** but it looks like it is not the right solution.

Many thanks

Comment: Please paste some code.

Comment: Hi, I used Yannici's code below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[CodeIgniter: Connection to your Database](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/connecting.html)**

Maybe the link above will help you out.
You have to set a new db connection for the specific company. In CodeIgniter it is really simple.

Combine it with **[THIS PROBLEM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271847/how-can-i-access-a-codeigniter-configuration-variable-from-a-model-controller)** to get access to the database settings setted in the database-config.

Example:

```
<?php
$config = array();
$config['hostname'] = $this->db->hostname;
$config['username'] = $this->db->username;
$config['password'] = $this->db->password;
$config['database'] = 'companydb';
$config['dbdriver'] = $this->db->dbdriver;

$companydb = $this->load->database($config);
$companydb->query('SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...');
?>
```

Comment: hi Yannici, thank you. Do you think it is possible to extend database class to read database name from session and then override the name stored in database.php? If yes, please post short code. thank you very much.

Comment: I don't know if it's working, but you can try to override the existing loaded database eg. `$this->db = $companydb;`